# custom push notifiactions to show every day

Tags: android, push-notification

I made an app for a shopping site that uses webview to display the website.I need the app to give a push notification every 24 hour ( e.g "Check our new collection !!") with a small icon , in simplest way.How can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can that be done ?

Most likely you need to use `AlarmManager` with specific action-intent. I think this is what you want. It's pretty designated for purposes just like this.

Look at this:

- [Use Android's AlarmManager to schedule an event](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/)